# Converting Ubuntu 20.04 boot from legacy to UEFI after installation

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-legacy

Dual booting.I installed my Ubuntu in legacy mode because windows(10) didn't recognize the USB in UEFI.
Is there any way to convert the grub from legacy to UEFI boot?
OR is there any way to re-install ubuntu in UEFI?

I tried almost all things but couldn't get the USB to recognize in UEFI!

Comment: Might be a bios setting preventing boot from USB.  Win 10 has nothing to do with it.  Edit your question with computer make and model at least.  Check bios for secure boot, fast boot, and/or boot from USB settings.  First two turn off/disable, third turn on/enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the USB recognized by making a bootable USB using Rufus and changing the file system into GMT!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can check in your BIOS settings

1. In Advanced -> USB Configurations -> Enable both front and rear USB ports.
2. In the boot option. Turn off secure boot and enable USB boot support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to get the USB recognized by making a bootable USB using Rufus and changing the file system into GMT!